# What are standard ways to indicate that an item is being deleted?

Tags: mobile-web, ux-designer, deletion

I have a PWA that stored rather large amount of data in IndexedDB, and when a user decides to delete parts of it, it takes a lot of time (10-30 sec, even a minute). Currently, when the user click delete, the card that represents the item becomes grey, similar to a disabled form control or button, and when the operation finishes, I remove the card altogether. Is it an acceptable solution? What are the best practices to indicate such a long deletion process? We are developers left without a UI/UX designer, and struggle with such questions.

I have this:

[image: Active state]
[image: Deleted state]

Comment: can you include a sketch or diagram to visualize what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is on the right track. One thing to consider is that you'll either want to make the user confirm the deletion, or undo it afterward (UX principle of error prevention and recovery). Then, you'll let the user know what's happening while the deletion is going on - you could use a spinner on the card that's being deleted.

[image: cards with deletion message and loader on the card that is being deleted]

After the item has been deleted, you'll show a message (toast or banner).

[image: Dropbox's example of a deleted card message]

[image: Chat history deletion confirmation]

Comment: Thanks, undoing is not an option, it is an offline PWA, once the data has been deleted, we would need to access an online resource and run a 4-5 min process to re-download what has been deleted.